# What's the Equivalent of Oracle's NULLS FIRST in DB2?

Tags: sql, db2

Does DB2 have anything like ORDER BY ord_col NULLS FIRST?

Answer (score 11):

You use a `case` in the `order by` to sort nulls before other values:

```
select  *
from    YourTable
order by
        case when col1 is null then 0 else 1 end
,       col1
```

Comment: +1 This is the most general solution. A bit more verbose than using `COALESCE` or `NVL`, but it will work for any datatype in `col1` and it's quite simple.

Answer (score 3):

There is nothing such like `ORDER BY ord_col NULLS FIRST` in DB2, but you can use functions to get the same behavior:

```
CREATE TABLE TV84 (
   CORN CHAR(2) NOT NULL
  ,COUAG CHAR(4) NOT NULL
  ,DDFA DATE NOT NULL
  ,MTFAC1 INTEGER
);

INSERT INTO TV84 (CORN,COUAG,DDFA,MTFAC1)
VALUES ('01','0309',TO_DATE('10.05.2008','MM.DD.YYYY'),2520);
INSERT INTO TV84 (CORN,COUAG,DDFA,MTFAC1)
VALUES ('01','0309',TO_DATE('12.14.2008','MM.DD.YYYY'),NULL);
INSERT INTO TV84 (CORN,COUAG,DDFA,MTFAC1)
VALUES ('01','0309',TO_DATE('10.15.2009','MM.DD.YYYY'),6452);
INSERT INTO TV84 (CORN,COUAG,DDFA,MTFAC1)
VALUES ('02','0309',TO_DATE('06.16.2010','MM.DD.YYYY'),1283);
INSERT INTO TV84 (CORN,COUAG,DDFA,MTFAC1)
VALUES ('02','0309',TO_DATE('08.28.2010','MM.DD.YYYY'),NULL);
```

- With the `COALESCE` scalar function:

```
SELECT CORN, COUAG, DDFA, MTFAC1
FROM TV84
ORDER BY COALESCE(MTFAC1,0);

CORN COUAG DDFA       MTFAC1
---- ----- ---------- -----------
01   0309  14.12.2008           -
02   0309  28.08.2010           -
02   0309  16.06.2010        1283
01   0309  05.10.2008        2520
01   0309  15.10.2009        6452
```

- Or more explicit with the `ROW_NUMBER` OLAP function (see [OLAP functions](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/db2luw/v9/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.db2.udb.admin.doc/doc/r0023461.htm)):

```
SELECT CORN, COUAG, DDFA, MTFAC1
  ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY MTFAC1 NULLS FIRST) RN
FROM TV84
ORDER BY RN;

CORN COUAG DDFA       MTFAC1      RN
---- ----- ---------- ----------- --------------------
01   0309  14.12.2008           -                    1
02   0309  28.08.2010           -                    2
02   0309  16.06.2010        1283                    3
01   0309  05.10.2008        2520                    4
01   0309  15.10.2009        6452                    5
```

**Update**: For the OLAP function solution, if you need to order by an additional column, it's better to use the `RANK` or `DENSE_RANK` functions:

```
SELECT CORN, COUAG, DDFA, MTFAC1
  ,RANK() OVER (ORDER BY MTFAC1 NULLS FIRST) RNK
FROM TV84
ORDER BY RNK;

CORN COUAG DDFA       MTFAC1      RNK
---- ----- ---------- ----------- --------------------
01   0309  14.12.2008           -                    1
02   0309  28.08.2010           -                    1
02   0309  16.06.2010        1283                    3
01   0309  05.10.2008        2520                    4
01   0309  15.10.2009        6452                    5
```

Comment: Thank you! The `NVL(MTFAC1,0)` function works too, but I think this is supported only starting from version 9.7 of DB2 database.

Answer (score 1):

No, I don't believe so.

You can emulate the behaviour with something like:

```
select 0 as seq, col1, col2 from tbl where col1 is null
union all
select 1 as seq, col1, col2 from tbl where col1 is not null
order by 1, 2
```

and then ignoring the `seq` column in your data processing code.

Comment: That produces a quite expensive execution plan (two `null` checks on `col1` for the entire `tbl`), while being quite intrusive on the original query itself (additional `seq` column, difficult to add additional filters, `order by` clauses, etc). Compared to other solutions with a `case` statement, I wouldn't do it this way...

Comment: Lukas, that's not actually true according to the analysis I carried out. The fact that you differentiate the to parts means that (1) the index is fully used to efficiently get each part (null and not null) and (2) a multi-thread execution engine ran them in parallel then combine them. A `case` variant was running a per-row function on _every_ row, which was horribly inefficient.

Comment: nice! I hadn't thought of that possibility. So your CBO (or whatever that is called in DB2) transformed the `union all` away in order to parallelise the two individual selects. That's not very obvious but quite smart. Is that a documented query transformation in DB2?